# deploy SSRS report from within dotnet application

Tags: .net, reporting-services

I have a SSRS reporting project with some Datasources and Reports defined.
I alsohave a VB.NET application, in which the reports are shown.

I would like to embed this project into a deployable application , that I package into one executable, so end users can install the package, and can somehow deploy the reports onto their ReportServer. Probably I also need to provide a way the end user can define the connection string to their Report server?

The same goes with a SSIS package that I have created; I also want to embed that into the same package.

So, how can I embed both SSRS and SSIS projects into my VB.NET application?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSRS provides a web service which you can use for these tasks. You would simply capture the base URL to the Reporting Services instance and you can then call the methods on the web service to deploy the reports;

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server-web-service/report-server-web-service?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: That seems a valid method; I will look into it. Thanks!